# Why doesn't Python UAC Request work for paths with spaces in them?

Tags: python-3.x, admin, uac, python-3.6, administrator

I'm using `ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW` in order to run a script with administrator privileges. I do NOT want to use `win32api` because that is a package that requires installation, where `ctypes` does not. I've realized that using the following script (simplified), if the script is run in a directory with a space in it (e.g. "C:\Users\User\Documents\My Folder"), even if the UAC request is granted, the script does not gain administrator privileges. As long as the script is not executed in a directory with a space in the name, it works fine.

The script:

```
# Name of script is TryAdmin.py
import ctypes, sys, os

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if is_admin():
    print("I'm an Admin!")
    input()
else:
    b=ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None,'runas',sys.executable,os.getcwd()+'\\TryAdmin.py',None,1)

if b==5:  # The user denied UAC Elevation

    # Explain to user that the program needs the elevation
    print("""Why would you click "No"? I need you to click yes so that I can
have administrator privileges so that I can execute properly. Without admin
privileges, I don't work at all! Please try again.""")
    input()

    while b==5:  # Request UAC elevation until user grants it
        b=ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None,'runas',sys.executable,os.getcwd()+'\\TryAdmin.py',None,1)

        if b!=5:
            sys.exit()
        # else
        print('Try again!')
        input()
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What's wrong with sys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question [ShellExecute: Verb "runas" does not work for batch files with spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247518/shellexecute-verb-runas-does-not-work-for-batch-files-with-spaces-in-path) is similar but in C++.

It has a nice explanation of the possible reason for your issue, related to quoting issues.

If you quote the arguments (or at least the second one) you should fix the issue.

```
b=ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
    None, 'runas',
    '"' + sys.executable + '"',
    '"' + os.getcwd() + '\\TryAdmin.py' + '"',
    None, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it had something to do with the way some language deals with paths/quotes, knowing that batch requires quotes around spaced paths. In fact, I tried some quoting, but I evidently didn't try the correct combination. I'm upset that I spent 50 rep on what turned out to be a simple solution, but at least I now know. I'm surprised that nowhere could I find this type of question already being asked concerning Python.